# Construct a Magic Square by a given number of rows

Tags: php, magic-square

I'm trying to build an application in simple PHP but could be done in any language.

I want the user to enter number of rows and the output will be the magic square of it.

For example, for $rows=3:

```
8-1-6
3-5-7
4-9-2
```

Notice that in every row,column,diagonal the sum of numbers is equal to 15.

There is a method for constructing this with an odd number of rows. I DONT want that. I want the program to ACTUALLY calculate numbers, row-sums, column-sums and diagonal-sums, doesn't matter if the input is odd or even.

Do you have any idea how to go about doing this? Right now i'm drowning in a sea of loops.
HELP!

Comment: No, thank god no, it was something i've been wondering how to do for a long time.

Comment: You could brute-force it with backtracking.

Comment: It this some kind of Sudoku generator?

Comment: No, it generates a square with equal sums of rows, columns and diagonals. If you like to watch it work, you can go to the link i embedded down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, after a further search I found a JAVA applet that does it:
[link text](http://www.dr-mikes-math-games-for-kids.com/how-to-make-a-magic-square.html)

It's pretty sweet thinking about the extensive mechanism working behind this seemingly simple algorithm.